How to use ANSI Sequences to get the hovering position of the mouse in a python terminal?
Whe I use the python textual module's button widgets, it can detect the hovering position of the mouse in my terminal, and when it is over a button, the button would change its color. How did it do that by using hacks.
I've tried out the sequences \x1b[?1h\x1b[?9h\x1b[?38h\x1b[?47h\x1b[?1000h\x1b[?1001h, but when I printed out the seqs, it doesn't change anything.

The terminal can be put in to a mode where it sends mouse coordinates via stdin. Textual reads stdin to know where the mouse pointer is.
When Textual renders output, its keeps a structure in memory that describes where every widget is on the "screen". It can use this information to calculate the widget that is under the mouse at any given time.

How did Textual read? And what is the mode?

Too vague for a good answer.

He is the project author. I also have a project which can read the mouse position in the terminal. None of us will "know by heart" the mode's name, os escape sequence to activate it - that is in the code.

Terminedia's code for setting up the terminal and interpreting the sequences, looking for mouse events is here: https://github.com/jsbueno/terminedia/blob/5f1dfec7204715a29008543cb26bb9414be5f257/terminedia/input.py#L470

I'm using Windows Terminal, so it runs on Windows. Since Windows doesn't support termios and its dependencies, so I can't run your project @jsbueno

terminedia works on windows, but not the mouse part. The mouse support is posix only. Patches welcome. :-)

Print the sequence \e[?1003h\e[?1006h.

1000 is the standard mouse protocol which only reports clicks and releases, but not mouse movements. Not good for you.
1001 is "Highlight tracking", at least in xterm. I'm not familiar with this mode, but according to ctlseqs.html it "requires a cooperating program, else xterm will hang". I don't know if any terminal other than xterm implements this. I'm sure this is not what you're looking for.
1002 reports mouse drag events, i.e. reports movements but only if you have a button pressed down. We're getting there.
1003 reports mouse movements even if no button is pressed. This is what you're looking for.

Independently of the above, every mouse-aware app should enable the 1006 extension, which reports the three numbers encoded in decimal.
Without that extension, the button (action) and the two coordinates are reported as single bytes: the value plus 32. This makes it impossible to report columns/rows above 223, or if for whatever reason the stream needs to be valid UTF-8 or undergoes some charset conversion then above 95 (charset conversion might even result in faulty coordinates, or added/removed input characters).
I believe that nowadays pretty much every terminal supports this extension, however, there might be exceptions. Even though your app should enable this extension, ideally it should still parse and interpret the received mouse events if they don't use this extension. Luckily the old-fashioned and the extended mouse event reports look different, they don't conflict, you can unambiguously tell which one arrived and handle accordingly.

See the previously linked ctlseqs.html for a description of the first value in the response escape sequence: how it encodes the button (or lack thereof), wheel, keyboard modifiers; and also how the trailing M or m letter encodes a button release in the 1006 extension differently than the legacy protocol.
